# Need some help configuring a WSO2 Proxy Service

Tags: wso2-esb

How do I get inbound the SOAP payload converted to a HTTP Post payload so that it can be sent via my HTTPEndpoint

An example would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Which Platform? Which SOAP Framework? What's at the "HTTPEndpoint" (software)?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the endpoint format to pox to create a plain xml message to be posted. See for example: http://charithaka.blogspot.nl/2010/07/message-format-transformations-with.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to SOAP to REST conversion? In that case it would be like following.

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="testProxy" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="messageType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <http method="POST" uri-template="http://localhost:9000"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

The axis2 messageType property decides the MessageFormatter used to format the message before sending out. In this case its application/xml so the Content-Type of the outgoing POST request will be application/xml.

Comment: Thanks - how do I use only part of the soap payload in my POSTed HTTP payload I have ---  <level1><level2><level3>data_1</level3><level3>data_2</level3><level3>data_n</level3></level2></level1>   --- I want to POST <level2><level3>data_1</level3><level3>data_2</level3><level3>data_n</level3></level2>   as I am using <level1> as part of my filtering

Comment: If you just want to drop the <level1> tag, you can use the enrich mediator

Comment: example config: <enrich>
               <source xmlns:m="http://your_namespace"
                       clone="true"
                       xpath="$body/m:level1/m:level2"/>
               <target type="body"/>
            </enrich>